# Pandas finds NaNs where there are floats instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I was trying to convert the floats in a column into int.

```
zbill['ACTIVITY START MONTH']=zbill['ACTIVITY START MONTH'].astype(int)
```

It returned this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

I thougth it was strange, since there should not be any NaN. So I got the rows where in theory there should be NaNs.

```
missing_values_list= zbill[zbill['ACTIVITY START MONTH'].isnull()].index.tolist()
zbill.iloc[missing_values_list]
```

What I found out is that actually there are no NaNs! But only floats... I get something like this:

```
A | B | ACTIVITY START MONTH 
______________________________
A | R | 11.0
W | S | 9,0
....
```

How is it even possible? Pandas do think that there are NaNs in that column.

```
zbill['ACTIVITY START MONTH'].isnull().values.any()
True
```

Why?

Comment: One of the errors you have made is using zbill.iloc[...] where you should have used zbill.loc[...]. Let me know if that solves your problem. Why don't you just look at zbill[zbill['ACTIVITY START MONTH'].isnull()] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For get rows with missing values or with infinitive values use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only:

```
df = zbill[zbill['ACTIVITY START MONTH'].isnull() | 
           np.isinf(zbill['ACTIVITY START MONTH']) ]
```

In your solution use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead `iloc` for selecting by labels, not by positions:

```
df = zbill.loc[missing_values_list]
```